# login with Entra ID in Unity WebGL

Tags: azure-active-directory, unity-webgl, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to add login functionality to my Unity app, using Entra ID (Azure active directory). I get how the basic flow of Oath2 works, but I am having trouble implementing it in Untiy. The problem is that Unity WebGL classifies as a singe page web app. Will MSAL.js library to make this work? Or is there an easier way to make this happen?

As I am new to Entra ID I started out using the "web app" protocol, but quickly noticed that using this would lead to problems storing the client_secret (it is not supposed to used in an app that runs fully on the client).

After I switched to single page, but I can't find how to start implementing this using Untiy. I did come across MSAL.JS but I am not sure if it is a good idea to try and implement that in Unity.